# Armhf binaries on aarch64

Tags: linux, arch-linux, arm, cpu-architecture, boinc

So I'm running Arch Linux (64 bit) on a Raspberry Pi 3. What I'm trying to do is running a few BOINC projects on this machine. While some projects (like SETI@home) supply proper aarch64 binaries that run flawlessly, most projects only support armhf. I tried to force these projects to supply work units to this aarch64 system, but the work unit almost instantly crashes with the following error: `execv: Exec format error`

Why is this happenning? I thought aarch64 systems can run armhf binaries. Isn't this the same thing as running x86 binaries on x86_64? Can I setup QEMU to run armhf binaries without much performance loss?

I hope this is the right place to ask this question.

Comment: I may have found the answer. According to https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/arm/aarch64 "A machine in AArch64 can only execute A64 instructions and cannot execute A32 or T32 instructions."